# How to call native Android keyboard for TextEdit

Tags: android

I'm using Samsung Galaxy A7 phone with TouchWiz interface. My question is it possible to call native Android keyboard for to input data in TextEdit? Now when i tap on TextEdit it show me TouchWiz keyboard, but in my app i need to use native Android keyboard

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think one can force an user to use any particular keyboard because Android provides this setting to user to set their preferred Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In your phone go to Settings>Language and input and uncheck TouchWiz keyboard

Comment: I need to call it programatically without any settings from user side